# How to get the whole strings with space in jinja2

Tags: python, string, list, jinja2

i use python, jinja2, GAE.

I have a python list passed to jinja2. The list looks like ['hi mate', 'hello world"].
But I only can get 'hi', 'hello' from the 'item'

```
{% for item in pyList %}
```

if I put it in

```
<input type="text" name="line1" value={{item}}>.
```

The left after the space is missed out.
How i can get the whole string?

Comment: It should work. Can you please show whole code?

Comment: I found if it is {{item}}, it worked. It shows 'hi mate', but if i put it in  
                                                                          <input type="text" name="line1" value={{item}}>
the value only get the first word 'hi'.

Comment: Enclose {{item}} with quotes, it will work.

Comment: rajpy, yes. <input type="text" name="line1" value="{{item}}"> works.

Answer (score 3):

Since your values have a space, you have to quote them. Otherwise the HTML looks like

```
<input type="text" name="line1" value=hi mate>
```

`mate` is then considered a custom attribute, and in effect it does nothing; and `hi` gets set as the value. When you quote it though:

```
<input type="text" name="line1" value="hi mate">
```

Now the entire string in quotes is set as the value

Comment: If the value of your `value` attribute is from a variable, you can do this:
`<input type="text" name="line1" value="{{item}}">`.  I did it and it worked.